# HTTP error fetching URL. Status=500 while getting data from a website

Tags: scala, web-scraping, jsoup, scalaj-http

I'm trying to get data from a website using **Jsoup**, the website is taking **payload** in **Json** (`{"SEARCH_VALUE":"ab","STARTS_WITH_YN":false,"ACTIVE_ONLY_YN":false,"ELECTRONIC_NOTARY_ONLY_YN":false,"REMOTE_NOTARY_ONLY_YN":false}`) with **post** request but it is giving **500 error**. I tried to get cookies from the home page which return null ({}).

```
scala version: "2.13.1"

sbt version: "1.2.8"

jsoup version: "1.15.3"
```

here is my code in scala

```
  val homePageUrl = "https://firststop.sos.nd.gov/search/notary"
  val searchPage = "https://firststop.sos.nd.gov/api/Records/notarysearch"
  val jsoup =Jsoup.connect(searchPage)

  val response = jsoup.data("ACTIVE_ONLY_YN","false" )
    .data("SEARCH_VALUE", "ab")
    .data("ELECTRONIC_NOTARY_ONLY_YN", "0")
    .data("REMOTE_NOTARY_ONLY_YN", "false")
    .data("STARTS_WITH_YN", "false")
    .post()
  println(response)
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=500, URL=[https://firststop.sos.nd.gov/api/Records/notarysearch]
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:890)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:366)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.post(HttpConnection.java:360)
```

What I tried:

I've set **timeout** and **userAgent** such as

```
  val jsoup =Jsoup.connect(searchPageUrl).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36").timeout(0).ignoreHttpErrors(true).ignoreContentType(true).followRedirects(true)

  val response = jsoup.data("ACTIVE_ONLY_YN","false" )
    .data("SEARCH_VALUE", "ab")
    .data("ELECTRONIC_NOTARY_ONLY_YN", "0")
    .data("REMOTE_NOTARY_ONLY_YN", "false")
    .data("STARTS_WITH_YN", "false")
    .post()

  println(response)
```

I got same error,

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  {"code":"api/Records","message":"Internal Error Occurred","internalerror":null,"title":""}
 </body>
</html>
```

Then I tried to set header

```
  val payload = """{SEARCH_VALUE:"ab",STARTS_WITH_YN:false,ACTIVE_ONLY_YN:false,ELECTRONIC_NOTARY_ONLY_YN:false,REMOTE_NOTARY_ONLY_YN:false}""".stripMargin

   val request: Connection.Response = Jsoup.connect(searchPageUrl)
     .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
     .method(Connection.Method.POST)
     .ignoreContentType(true)
     .requestBody(payload)
     .execute()
   val responseBody = request.body()
   println(responseBody)
```

but it is still giving 500 error.

I have also tried it with `scalaj.http`

```
  val payload = """{SEARCH_VALUE:"ab",STARTS_WITH_YN:false,ACTIVE_ONLY_YN:false,ELECTRONIC_NOTARY_ONLY_YN:false}""".stripMargin

  val response = Http(searchPageUrl).postData(payload).header("Content-Type", "application/json").asString
    println(response)

  val responseBody = response.body

  val json = responseBody.parseJson
  println(json)
```

I've got error

```
HttpResponse({"code":"api/Records","message":"Internal Error Occurred","internalerror":null,"title":""},500,TreeMap(Access-Control-Allow-Headers -> Vector(Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Content-Encoding, Authorization), Access-Control-Allow-Methods -> Vector(*), Access-Control-Allow-Origin -> Vector(*), Access-Control-Expose-Headers -> Vector(session-timeout, Request-Context), Cache-Control -> Vector(no-cache), Connection -> Vector(close), Content-Length -> Vector(90), Content-Type -> Vector(application/json; charset=utf-8), Date -> Vector(Wed, 30 Aug 2023 07:29:59 GMT), Expires -> Vector(-1), Pragma -> Vector(no-cache), Request-Context -> Vector(appId=cid-v1:df24017c-37e9-4e1c-afab-260d80eaaeea), Server -> Vector(State of North Dakota), session-timeout -> Vector(0), Set-Cookie -> Vector(ASP.NET_SessionId=j3ioe0kyrrkaqrwlymi0dq0r; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax), Status -> Vector(HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error), X-AspNet-Version -> Vector(4.0.30319), X-Content-Type-Options -> Vector(nosniff), X-XSS-Protection -> Vector(1;  mode=block)))
{"code":"api/Records","internalerror":null,"message":"Internal Error Occurred","title":""}
```

Where I'm doing wrong , is there any other way to do get data from this website ?

Comment: @GaëlJ Questions are always asked for help doesn't matter what type of question , If you are not interested to answer, don't give any suggestion. 
Moreover there are a lot of people working on scraping, we are not harming any website.
Thank you.

Comment: My point is: you are making requests to a website and having errors 500, except the owner of this website, nobody here will be able to give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues that have to be handled here:

1. There is an authentication cookie in the post request - you must fetch it first and use it later.
2. The server is very strict and demands that the request will incluce all the right headers as they are in the browser.
3. The search data should be in a json format.

To get the cookie - open a connection to this url - https://firststop.sos.nd.gov/api/GroupItems/Auth and store the cookie for later usage. Also add `ignoreContentType`, since it's json and jsoup will not parse it (but anyway you don't need the content).
As for 2 and 3 you can see how I did it in the following (Java) code:

```
String search_url = "https://firststop.sos.nd.gov/api/Records/notarysearch";
String auth_url = "https://firststop.sos.nd.gov/api/GroupItems/Auth";
try {           
    Connection.Response con = Jsoup.connect(auth_url)
        .ignoreContentType(true)
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();
    System.out.println(con.cookies());
        
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(search_url)
        .requestBody("{\"SEARCH_VALUE\":\"ab\",\"STARTS_WITH_YN\":false,\"ACTIVE_ONLY_YN\":false,\"ELECTRONIC_NOTARY_ONLY_YN\":false,\"REMOTE_NOTARY_ONLY_YN\":false}")
        .cookies(con.cookies())
        .ignoreContentType(true)
        .header("Host", "firststop.sos.nd.gov")
        .header("Accept" ,"*/*")
        .header("Accept-Language" ,"en-US,en;q=0.5")
        .header("Accept-Encoding" ,"gzip, deflate, br")
        .header("Referer" ,"https://firststop.sos.nd.gov/search/notary")
        .header("authorization" ,"undefined")
        .header("content-type" ,"application/json")
        .header("Content-Length" ,"131")
        .header("Origin" ,"https://firststop.sos.nd.gov")
        .header("DNT" ,"1")
        .header("Connection" ,"keep-alive")
        .header("Sec-Fetch-Dest" ,"empty")
        .header("Sec-Fetch-Mode" ,"cors")
        .header("Sec-Fetch-Site" ,"same-origin")
        .header("Pragma" ,"no-cache")
        .header("Cache-Control" ,"no-cache")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0")
        .post();
        System.out.println(doc);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

There is also the `content-length` header - I've copied its value from the browser, but you will have to write a method that calculates it.
Now all you have to do is to parse the output for your needs.